# How do you cast a LinqToSql Table<TEntity> as a Table<IEntity> where TEntity : IEntity?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, generics, dblinq

I'm trying to use DbLinq with a SQLite database, but I'm running into a problem when I try to cast an `ITable` as a `Queryable<TEntity>`.

There is a known bug in DbLinq ([Issue 211](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/issues/detail?id=211)), which might be the source of my problem, but I wanted to make sure my code is sound and, if it is, find out if there might be something I can do to work around the bug.

Here is the generic repository method that attempts to do the cast:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    return Table.Cast<TEntity>(); // Table is an ITable
}
```

This compiles, but if I pass in the interface `IPerson` for `TEntity` and the type of the entities in the table is `Person` (where `Person : IPerson`), I'm getting this error from DbLinq:

> S0133: Implement QueryMethod Queryable.Cast.

**Why am I trying to do this?**

I have a library project that doesn't know the type of the entity until runtime, but it does know the interface for the entity. So, I'm trying to cast to the interface type so that my library project can consume the data.

**Questions:**

1. Am I attempting an impossible cast or is this definitely a bug in DbLinq?
2. How else could I go about solving my problem?

**Update**

I reworked my repository class so it now takes a `TEntity` *and* a `TEntityBase`, where `TEntity` is the actual type of the entity, and `TEntityBase` is the interface that I'm trying to cast to. Importantly, I now have the following `where` clause in my class definition:

```
where TEntity : class, TEntityBase
```

This allows me to store my `Table` property as a `Table<TEntity>` instead of an `ITable`, which allows me to use `AsEnumerable()` (as Stephen suggested). Here is the revised method:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntityBase> GetAll()
{
    return Table.AsEnumerable().Select(e => (TEntityBase)e);
}
```

And so far, that *seems* to do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a bug, but understand that implementing a LINQ provider is an absolutely huge endeavor. Even (Microsoft's) LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities have their own restrictions on exactly which LINQ queries/operations they support or do not support.

If returning `IEnumerable<T>` is acceptable, then you could work around the lack of support for `Queryable.Cast` by calling `AsEnumerable` before calling `Cast`. However, this restricts how your DAL can be used: since `IQueryable<T>` is no longer returned, further queries (e.g., `Where` clauses) won't be passed through to the DB layer.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen! I think returning IEnumerable<T> would be acceptable for my purposes, but I'm not seeing a method or an extension called `AsEnumerable()` on my `ITable` object. Could I be missing a namespace reference?

Answer (score 2):

I agree it sounds like a bug.  You could try the following which will do the same thing

```
return Table.Select<TEntity>(tbl => (TEntity)tbl)
```

You might have to add a where : ITable to the method definition as well.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Alas, same problem as with Stephen's answer. `Select()` does not appear to be available for an ITable.